# Sort a data frame when column name is assigned in a variable

Tags: r

I am new to R and hence my question is likely to be basic. I tried researching the answer before posting here however didn't get the answer I was looking for.

I am trying to order a data frame on the basis of certain columns. The column is dynamic and depends on a certain "outcome" which would be from a vector of "validoutcomes".

`validoutcomes <- c("A","B","C")`

if outcome is "A" then I am supposed to read data from column 11. For "B" its columns 17 and for "C" it is 23.

I renamed the columns so that it is easier for my readability and alignment with  validoutcomes. "input" is my source data from the CSV.

`colnames(input)[11] <- validoutcomes[1]
 colnames(input)[17] <- validoutcomes[2]
 colnames(input)[23] <- validoutcomes[3]`

I then tried to sort using

`statelist <- statelist[order(statelist$outcome)]`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt was more accurate. Since I do not have your data I will just use the iris data set,

```
 iris_ordered_on_Sepal_Length <- iris[order(iris$Sepal.Length),]
```

or if you use [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/),

```
iris_dt <- data.table(iris)
iris_dt[order(Sepal.Length)]
```

data.table will make renaming easier too,

```
setnames(input, c("colname_11, "colname_17", "colname_23"), validoutcomes[1 : 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the likely answer. I am not sure if this is the best answer but it worked for me.

Since `$` is used to call the colnames, R was looking for a column name as `outcome`. However all it needed was square brackets`[]`. I replaced it and so far seems to be working for me.

```
statelist <- statelist[order(statelist[outcome])]
```

I am still very interested in knowing if there is a better solution or if someone sees issue with my observation.